# Study the Locally Lipschitz condition of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a,b\in \mathbb R^+$ and let $f:A\times\mathbb R$ such that
$$f(x,y)=\frac{y}{\cos\left(a x\right)+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+b}\sin\left(a x\right)}$$
where $A=\{x|\cos\left(a x\right)+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+b}\sin\left(a x\right)\neq0\}$. My question: is this a locally lipschitz function?

I think that this is true, because the denominator of $f$ is continuous in $A$ and
$$\left|f(x_1,y_1)-f(x_2,y_2)\right|\leq \sup_{x\in A}\left\{\frac{1}{\cos\left(a x\right)+\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+b}\sin\left(a x\right)}\right\} \cdot \left|y_1-y_2\right|$$
Is it true?

Comment: What is the role of $R$? Any $\mathcal{C^1}$ function on some open subset of $\mathrb{R}^d$ is locally Lipschitz, so the answer is positive.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan sorry, R was a typo. Thank you